# Getting text from a spinner in android studios

Tags: java, android-studio, spinner

I have a spinner with 2 selections, "text1" and "text2". When I tried to get "text1" and log "text1" to see if I got it or not, I got this instead: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner{d963757 VFED..CL. ........ 389,1177-883,1230 #7f080094 app:id/spinner1}".

What am I doing wrong?

```
String getSpinnerName = "spinner" + "1";
Spinner spinner =  (Spinner) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(getSpinnerName, "id", getPackageName()));
final String spinnerText = spinner.toString();
Log.d(String.valueOf(LOG), spinnerText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are converting an object into String that's why.

```
final String spinnerText = spinner.toString();
```

if you want to get the values from spinner use below one.

```
final String spinnerText = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```